# Why Route In Terminal Work but Nothink Happen

Tags: python, flask, redirect, mysql-python, dropzone

Please Help

Why route in terminal work?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2024 00:20:04] "POST /classification/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2024 00:20:04] "GET /hasil/True-NORMAL2-IM-0421-0001.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But it doesn't move to `classification.html` with params. Is that anything wrong?

Code :

```
dropzone = Dropzone(app)
@app.route('/classification/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def classification():
    p = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files.get('file')
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_PATH'],f.filename))
        model = load_model('static/model/TA_resnet50 epoch50 imgsize200.h5')
        model.make_predict_function()
        img_path = "static/upload_images/"+f.filename
        p = predict_label(img_path, model)
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO riwayat (userid, tanggal, hasil_klasifikasi, kode_citra) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', (session.get('userid'),  '11/12/2014', p, f.filename))
        cnx.commit()
        img_name = f.filename
        p = True
    
    if p:
         print("Reached redirect")
         return redirect(url_for('hasil', p_val=p, img_name_val=img_name, _external=True ))
         
    return render_template("classification.html")

@app.route('/hasil/<p_val>-<img_name_val>',  methods=['GET'])
def hasil(p_val, img_name_val):
    return render_template("classification.html", predict=p_val, img_name=img_name_val)
```

when route hasil run the page move to classification.html with params

Comment: What do you mean by "move to"?  The first request handles the database action, then redirects to `/hasil`.  That clearly happens.  The hasil route then displays "classification.html".  It doesn't do a redirect, so you won't see anything in the log.

Comment: i tried to move to another route(about.html), it show in the log but doesnt move too
sorry for my english

Comment: OK, but remember that `render_template` just sends output.  It doesn't cause a redirect, so you won't see anything in the logs.  `redirect` sends something to the browser which forces it to make a new request.  That appears in the log.

Comment: do you have any suggest when the `p = True` it make refresh the page with param or go to the same page with param?

Comment: I don't see what you're getting at.  In the setup you have there, you don't need the `hasil` route nor the redirect at all.  Your `classification` route can either display `classification.html` by itself, or display it with the parameters.  Right?  Just replace the `return redirect` line with the final `return render_template` line.